# My While Loop Won't Stop At Condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm running a card game where both players take turns picking cards and the player goes forward that many number of spaces. In this case, once either player reaches the number 25 or greater, they've hit Home and the game is supposed to stop.

```
//This is the function that plays the entire game
    void play(int size, int &player1, int &player2, int cardPile[], int board[]){
        displayRules();

        while(player1 < 25 || player2 < 25){
        cout << "\nPlayer 1's turn!" << endl;
        takeTurn(size, player1, cardPile, board, player2);
        showState(player1, player2);
        cout << "\nPlayer 2's turn!" << endl;
        takeTurn(size, player2, cardPile, board, player1);
        showState(player1, player2);
        }

    }
```

My while loop continues looping after both players have hit 25 even though I've set the conditions to loop while either player 1's value is less than 25 or player 2's value is less than 25.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void play(int size, int &player1, int &player2, int cardPile[], int board[]);
void displayRules();
int takeTurn(int size, int &player, int cardPile[], int board[], int &opposingPlayer);
int shuffleDeck(int size, int cardPile[]);
int switchPlaces(int &player, int &opposingPlayer);
int obstacles(int &player, int board[]);
void showState(int &player1, int &player2);
void youWin(int &player1, int &player2);


int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int board[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int cardPile[size] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    play(size, player1, player2, cardPile, board);
    return 0;
}

//This is the function that plays the entire game
void play(int size, int &player1, int &player2, int cardPile[], int board[]){
    displayRules();

    while(player1 < 25 || player2 < 25){
    cout << "\nPlayer 1's turn!" << endl;
    takeTurn(size, player1, cardPile, board, player2);
    showState(player1, player2);
    cout << "\nPlayer 2's turn!" << endl;
    takeTurn(size, player2, cardPile, board, player1);
    showState(player1, player2);
    }

}

//This function does a single turn for each player
int takeTurn(int size, int &player, int cardPile[], int board[],int &opposingPlayer){
    shuffleDeck(size, cardPile);
    int i = 0;
    if(cardPile[i] == 0)
        cout << "You drew a Lose a turn card! You lose a turn!" << endl;

    else if(cardPile[i] == 5)
        cout << "You drew a Switch Places card! You must switch places with the other player!" << endl,
        switchPlaces(player, opposingPlayer);

    else
    cout << "You drew a " << cardPile[i] << "!";
        switch(cardPile[i]){
        case 1:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[i] << " space on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[i];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[i] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[i];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[i] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[i];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[i] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[i];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;

        }

}

//This function shuffles the deck of cards
int shuffleDeck(int size, int cardPile[]){

    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            int index = rand() % size;
            int temp = cardPile[i];
            cardPile[i] = cardPile[index];
            cardPile[index] = temp;
    }

}


//This is the function that tells a player when they have ran into an
//obstacle and moves them back the appropriate number of spaces
int obstacles(int &player, int board[]){
    if(player == 1)
        player -= 1,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;
    else if(player == 4)
        player -= 1,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;
    else if(player == 8)
        player -= 2,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 2 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 12)
        player -= 3,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 3 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 16)
        player -= 2,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 2 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 20)
        player -= 1,
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;
}
```

Where did I go wrong with the while loop condition?

EDIT: Here is some output of one of the tests I ran.

```
Welcome to GoHome! The main objective of this game is to reach Home first.
The basic rules of the game are as follows:

-To begin the player with the shortest name goes first.
-Each player picks a card that has a number on it and the player must moves forward that many number of spaces.
-If a card says 'Lose A Turn', the player does nothing and theturn moves to the next player.
-If a card says 'Switch Places', that player is allowed to switch places with any player on the board.
-If a player lands on an obstacle, that player must move back that many number of spaces.
-If a player lands another obstacle while moving backwards, then it does not have to move backwards again.

0
0

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 3 of the board.
Player 2 is at Start!


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!
You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!

Player 1 is on spot 3 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 3 of the board.

3
3

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!
You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!

Player 1 is on spot 3 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 3 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 3 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 6 of the board.

3
6

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 7 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 6 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 7 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 7 of the board.

7
7

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 10 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 7 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 10 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 11 of the board.

10
11

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 11 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 11 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 11 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 14 of the board.

11
14

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 15 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 14 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 15 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 15 of the board.

15
15

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 18 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 15 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 18 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 19 of the board.

18
19

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 19 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 19 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 19 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 22 of the board.

19
22

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 23 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 22 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 1! Move forward 1 space on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 23 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 23 of the board.

23
23

Player 1's turn!
You drew a 3! Move forward 3 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 26 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 23 of the board.


Player 2's turn!
You drew a 4! Move forward 4 spaces on the board!

Player 1 is on spot 26 of the board.
Player 2 is on spot 27 of the board.
```

Comment: Try to cut your code down to the smallest bit that shows behavior, you'll get Get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your condition says "while either player1 is less than 25, or player2 is less than 25, do the thing that it's in the loop". But this is definitely not what you want. Simply changing:

```
while(player1 < 25 || player2 < 25){
```

to

```
while(player1 < 25 && player2 < 25){
```

Will do the work, I think.

This is related to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), from logic.

Also, keep in mind that for the program to terminate when either player reached 25, you have to ask after **every** turn, i.e. after each takeTurn call.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Logically the && operators would make it so that only one of player 1 and player 2 would have to be on Home to make the game end. While the || operator would make it so that both player 1 and player 2 would have to be on Home for the game to end. Big mistake on my part. I added an if statement right before the start of the 2nd Taketurn call, so if player 1 was greater than or equal to 25 the loop would break or else it would continue on to player 2.